# Change cell colour when inserting notes in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to add notes to orders placed by customers and in need the cell to change colour to "Light Purple 2" when i insert the note. I can't seem to find an =If formula to change the colour if notes are inserted.

I also do not want it to affect the whole sheet because I leave notes in other cells but only want the cells in column G to change the colour with notes.

Please can someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: How are the notes added?

Comment: Its like the same was you insert comment in cells in excel. I right click on the cell and then click on insert note and then leave a note. It then shows on the cell with a small mark on the top right of the cell. But that mark is too small on my entire sheet and I often miss that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formating.
Select the Cells you want to apply the color to.
In your case you want to apply it to column G, so you can highlight column G then on the Format Tab go to **Conditional Formatting**.
Then under **Format rules** select *Custom formula is*, in the input box put `=NOT(ISBLANK(H:H))` this will check if the Column H has anything in it then it will apply color to it's aligned cell. You can change the column or cells inside the `ISBLANK` depending on where you which cell range you will put your comments.

Reference links:

- Conditional Format Rules: https://productivityspot.com/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-google-sheets/
- How ISBLANK works: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en

Comment: Some cells in my column G do not have notes. So I cant change the colour for all the cells in column g with the isblank formula.

Comment: It will change the colour only for those with notes, using the NOT in the formula. The notes in my example is coming from column H, if it contains notes then it will color the aligned cell in the column G.

Comment: I cannot provide a solution at this time becauce onChange Event Ojbect is not reporting active sheet or active range properly.  It was a google issue that they think they fixed but according to my experience they didn't.

Comment: @DanF it colours the cell as soon as it detects something in the cell. I do not want it to change colour then. I need it to only change colour when I insert a note in the cell. only some of my cells have notes when the customer has a special request. Could you please find a way to do that?

Comment: The built-in conditional formatting of Google sheets works by getting conditions from the sheet's cell/cell ranges, and can't be based on notes. What you can do is have a script that you will manually run or automatically run on edit, to get the range current notes then format those cells to set their background color. Another option would be to just make use of another column for your notes and apply conditional formatting, for that you can refer to my posted answer. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469398/change-cell-colour-when-inserting-notes-in-google-sheets